# OAuth Login valid for 2nd device

Tags: javascript, php, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

Im programming a client web-app for a device, on which the user cant interact with the device (no input, neither mouse nor keyboard).

I want to display google calendar on said device. To achieve that, I build a setup page where the user can authorize my app and I can request the user's calendar. (avaiable trough a web browser on any device with user input).

My question now is, if its achievable to make the login work for the no-input device. Both sites (setup and non-input-client site) run on the same url)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are various ways to achieve this. Here's just one way I came up with, based on breaking down the problem with simple logic.

You have two devices, the no-input device and the with-input device. Information needs to flow from the with-input device to the no-input device. Because the no-input device has no means to allow the user to input this information (duh!), the information needs to flow through a server.

So you'll have a server.

You need a way to send information from the user's with-input device to that same user's no-input device, not to some other user's no-input device. So on the with-input device, you need to tell the server which no-input device to send the information to. That means you must be able to identify the no-input device uniquely.

This can be achieved in various ways. The simplest would be to generate a cryptographically random number of sufficient length, let's say 256 bits, and display that number on the no-input device. You could do that in textual form, e.g. using base 64, or if the with-input device has a camera you could display it as a QR code. We'll call this the "device identifier" (even though strictly speaking it isn't an identifier, as you can generate more than one over time).

Enter (or scan) that "device identifier" on the with-input device. Then go through the OAuth authorization code grant flow on the with-input device, up to the point where you have the authorization code. Do not exchange it for an access token yet, but send the authorization code with the "device identifier" to your server (over a secure connection, obviously).

One the no-input device, get the authorization code from the server using the "device identifier" (over a secure connection, obviously). Since the no-input device has no input mechanism to find out *when* to go get that code, it will need to look for it over some time period. Polling is one simple way in which to achieve this (though not the most efficient one).

Now you have the authorization code on the no-input device. Exchange it from the no-input device for an access token and refresh token, and you're good to go. You have an access token and can call your (Google) API from the no-input device.

Note that the "device identifier" not only needs to be unique, it also must be virtually impossible to guess device identifiers currently in use. Otherwise, a hacker can poll the server for authorization codes. A cryptographically random number of 256 bits meets that requirement.

Comment: first of all: thank you for making such an effort! To be precise, Im trying to display a users google calendar on the non-input device. Now, I get the users access_token on the device-with-input, but there is no way to create a valid session with google using the access_token? The only way to create a session, is to login to your google account and permit my app ON the non-input device...

Comment: @ArEsiiX Reread my answer, I have (hopefully) clarified it a bit. Also, if you're not sure what I mean by "authorization code", read the [OAuth 2.0 specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749), especially [section 4.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1).